# Easy way to change custom post type name for permalinks?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I've pretty much finished building a site based around a theme that uses a custom post type called portfolio.

Now, having just switched my permalinks to a custom structure, posts of that type display as www.mywebsite.com/portfolio/postname

I want it to be called 'projects' instead of portfolio so it displays www.mywebsite.com/projects/postname

Changing the name throughout the site take forever as it's referenced on numerous occasions in the various php files.

Is there an easy way to change this without manually replacing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might not have understood your questions fully, but can't you just change the rewrite slug for your custom post type to /projects instead of /portfolio?

Comment: Thanks this seems exactly what I want. However I've changed it to 'rewrite' => 'projects', and it hasn't updated it. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you "flush" your permalinks? Just goto your permalinks settings, and press save.

Comment: Thank you. I was writing it incorrectly - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30857/rewrite-on-custom-post-type-permalink-not-working/30859#30859