# Rewrite on custom post type permalink not working?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

My theme has a custom post type called 'portfolio'.

I want the url to display 'projects' instead.  I've change the rewrite on the register_post_type function to 'projects' but it doesn't change the permalinks...

```
'rewrite' => 'projects'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rewrite accepts a boolean or array, try:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'projects' )
```

make sure to visit your permalinks settings page to flush rewrites after you make the change.